# QRcode and BarQRCode itextpdf

Tags: java, itext, awt, qr-code, barcode

I need to create a qrcode following some technical specifications, such as: qrcode symbol version(), modules(), modules width(), ECC level() and character set().
I have to use **itextpdf** library and what I obtain has to become and **awt.Image**.

I tried to use both **QRCode** and **BarcodeQRCode**. With QRCode I set symbol version, modules, modules width and ECC level. Then with BarcodeQRCode I set the characater set and I can obtain an awt.Image.

The problem is that I cannot pass the QRCode to BarcodeQRCode.
Do you know how solve this problem and obtain a complete qrcode/image using this library?

This is my code:

```
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer ();
    sb.append ( QRCODE_IDENTIFICATIVO );
    // other lines with the content of qrcode

    QRCode qrCode = new QRCode ();
    qrCode.setVersion ( versione );
    qrCode.at ( modulesWidth, modulesHeight );
    qrCode.setMatrixWidth ( modulesWidth );
    qrCode.setECLevel ( ErrorCorrectionLevel.M );

    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> qrParam = new HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object> ();
    qrParam.put ( EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M );
    qrParam.put ( EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8" );

    BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode ( sb.toString (), (int) mmToPt ( 30f ), (int) mmToPt ( 30f ), qrParam );
    return qrcode.createAwtImage ( Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE );
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to create a PDF file with a barcode? Or do you need to create an image (PNG or BMP or ...)?

Comment: I need to create an awt image with a QRCODE

Comment: If you do not need PDF functionality, then you should not use a PDF library. Use a barcode library instead, like Zxing. iText uses parts of the code of Zxing.

Comment: I must use this library. Sorry!

Comment: Why must you use a library that has only a partial implementation of an existing barcode library and has a lot of overhead if you are never going to use its main functionality? I am an employee of iText Software and I am telling you: if there is no PDF functionality whatsoever in your software, then please don't use iText. My sales colleagues might disagree but I want to give you good advice.

Comment: You're right. I know Zxing and I know that it is perfect, but the project where I work on uses yet the Itext library so it is preferible to continue to use this library, instead to use two difference library. 
Itext library has the possibility to do what I want, so why should I change and don't try to fix the problem with what I have?

Comment: By the way, which version of iText?

Comment: The version is the 2.7.1.

Comment: Version 2.7.1 of iText does not exist. You probably meant 2.1.7, which is a decade old, and is no longer supported by iText Software, my employer. I recommend that you upgrade to a newer version, either 5.5.13, which requires minimal code changes (only the imports need to change from `com.lowagie` to `com.itextpdf`), or to 7.1.4, which may require more code changes because it is not backwards compatible.

Comment: Sorry, I read the wrong library. I use itextpdf 5.5.0 e I use also lowagie (because I use jasper report). The version of jasper is the 6.2.1. But the lowagie don't support the qrcode

Comment: I understood how solve the problem. The version 4 is the version with 33 modules (or modules width). Therefore,when the barqrcode is defined, the second and third parameters set the number of modules and, so,  the version and the module width also. While the EncodeHintType has the information about the character and the error correction.

Comment: Post your last comment as an answer and I will upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood how solve the problem. 
The version 4 is the version with 33 modules (or with modules width=33). Therefore, when the barQRcode is initialized, the second and third parameters set the number of modules and, so, the version and the module width also. While the EncodeHintType has the information about the character and the error correction. In this way all the information are used without use the QRcode. It is:

```
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer ();
sb.append ( QRCODE_IDENTIFICATIVO );
// other lines with the content of qrcode

Map<EncodeHintType, Object> qrParam = new HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object> ();
qrParam.put ( EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M );
qrParam.put ( EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8" );

BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode ( sb.toString (), 33, 33, qrParam );
return qrcode.createAwtImage ( Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE );
```